# Please define one of these @NgModule.bootstrap

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-modules

"main.ts:12 Error: NG0403: The module AppModule was bootstrapped, but it does not declare "@NgModule.bootstrap" components nor a "ngDoBootstrap" method. Please define one of these.  at PlatformRef._moduleDoBootstrap "

bootstrap: [ ]